# Defining a logger in environment.rb does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, undefined

I am trying to make a custom logger. I read elsewhere that I can define my logger in environment.rb and use it in other files.

I have in environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

my_logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log")
my_logger.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new


# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

And I call the logger from, for example, a controller:

```
    my_logger.info "got here"
```

However, I obtain the error:

> Undefined local variable or method `my_logger' for

Any clues as to why this could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open file into writing/appending mode :

Try :

```
logfile = File.open('#{Rails.root}/log/my.log', 'a')  
my_logger = Logger.new(logfile)
my_logger.info 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: I think it is the fact that the variable my_logger is not found (note that I define it in environment.rb and use it in a controller file, such as users_controller.rb)

Comment: You can configure this into any initializer file .

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain own log :

```
my_logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log")
```

Comment: where do I define this logger? In the environment.rb?

Comment: Define into any initilizer file or create new one logger.rb and put inot /config directory .